# codeigniter only getting single digit params from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have an issue that I can't figure out.

I'm retrieving company records from my database.
Some of the companies have single digit ID's while others have 2 or 3 digit ID's.

If I view a company using the url: `domain.com/company/view/3`,
it will list the company.
When I add a contact to that company, the url looks like this: `domain.com/contact/add/3`
and everything works fine.

However, with the companies that have 2 or 3 digits here is what happens:

If I view a company using the url: `domain.com/company/view/54`
it will list the company just fine.
When I add a contact to that company, the URL looks like this: `domain.com/contact/add/5`.
So, it's taking off the last digit (4).

In case you need it, here is my controller:

```
public function add($id) {

            if (isset($_POST["add"]))
        {
            $this->Equipment_model->add($id);
            redirect('company/view/'.$id);
        }
    $data['locations']  = $this->Equipment_model->get_locations($id);
    $data['data'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('equipment/add', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Any idea what is causing this?

edit: htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|font|img|js|themes)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

my routes look like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Home";
$route['logout'] = "auth/logout";
$route['login'] = "auth/login";
//$route['(:any)'] = '';
$route['404_override'] = 'error/error_404';
```

**Update 2:** 
to simplify things i did a quick video and uploaded it to twitch so you can see what im talking about. http://www.twitch.tv/bnelsonjax/b/420079504

Comment: Do you have any custom routing rules in place? Can you also post the mod_rewrite portion of your .htaccess file in your root directory?

Comment: What generates that URL?

Comment: i edited to include my routes and htaccess. ty for your time.

Comment: Also, does it redirect once you type the URL in your browser?

Comment: edited again as I posted the root htacess which went to wordpress.

Comment: shomz, in this example im viewing a company, and then adding a contact to that company, once submitted its redirecting to the wrong param. I uploaded a video on twitch if you want to see it in action, im not very good at describing the issue since my terminology in php is mediocre.  twitch.tv/bnelsonjax/b/420079504

Comment: if you are passing the $id parameter in the URL (seen in domain.com/contact/add/5) you are using the GET method. but then you are testing for POST data (and subsequently not using that data)?

Comment: the POST as seen in my code above is for the form on the page used to add a contact.

Comment: anyone have an idea? im stuck and out of ideas

Comment: You need to show the code you're using to retrieve and display that ID in your `company/view` view. Because clearly the URL ID is working fine, as it is retrieving the correct company when viewing the `contact/add` URL. Somewhere you are goofing up your variables or something. I can see that you've named the ID `$data['data']` -- could be related to that...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be getting the ID back for your contact rather than your company.  Have you checked that logic?

Comment: ya i have, its not getting the contact logic, the contact id in this example was a 3 digit ID, i have verified that it is indeed stripping the digits from the parameters

Comment: i just uploaded a video of me showing the issue: http://www.twitch.tv/bnelsonjax/b/420079504